# all elements of a List * List

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do a list of tuples with 2 lists of like this:

```
["a", "b", "c"] ["a", "b", "c"]
```

to this:

```
[("a", "a"), ("a", "b"),("a", "c")], [("b", "a"), ("b", "b"), ("b", "c"), ("c", "a"), ("c", "b"), ("a", "c")]
```

so I'm trying this, but I don't know how can I make that work:

```
f [] [] = [[]]
f (x:xs) y =
         zip (repeat x) y: f xs y
```

Comment: Why `[[(String, String)]]` instead of `[(String, String)]`? You only seem to be treating the `("a", ...)` tuples separately; the `("b", ...)` and `("c", ...)` tuples are in the same list.

Comment: If you just want a single list, use the `Applicative` instance for lists: `f xs ys = (,) <$> xs <*> ys`.

Comment: your `f` is nearly correct, just `f [] _ = []` instead for the base case. (assuming you're actually trying to create a list of list of tuples instead of a list of tuples)

Comment: `f = liftA2 (,)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For explicit recursion, it's tough to beat:

```
f :: [a] -> [a] -> [[(a, a)]]
f [] _       = []
f _ []       = []
f (x:xs) yss = go x yss : f xs yss
  where
  go _ []     = []
  go x (y:ys) = (x, y): go x ys
```

However there's no reason to do this. This is the use case that list comprehensions were made for!

```
f xs ys = [[(x, y) | y <- ys] | x <- xs]
```

Comment: Missing `|` in `[[(x, y) | y <- ys] | x <- xs]`